# I can't return to windows

Tags: dual-boot

I have 3 partitions, C with windows, D for games and stuff, and H where my ubuntu is. I installed ubuntu with the "Something else" option and now i can't return to windows. I tried deleting the partition where linux is, but its still running. Please help! i want my windows back.

Ok so i  started gparted and thats what it appears https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG7WW.jpg.

Comment: Relax. What did you choose in the something else option? Please run gparted from the LiVeCD, take a screenshot of your disk layout with Alt+Printscreen and upload it to imgur. Then edit your question and include the link.

Comment: I have chosen to install ubuntu on the H: partition which is 10 gb and those 10 gb are from the D: partition. Now when i start the PC it doesen't ask me to choose windows or ubuntu it just starts ubuntu.

Comment: Rather than take a screen shot of `gparted`, it is easier to just run `parted -l` in a terminal and add the text to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running `sudo grub-install /dev/X`, X being the Hard drive's letters, like sda or hda?